# Selected option not displaying as selected after append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm building a string of HTML based on JSON data. In the HTML is a `<select>` with its `<option>`s. If the `<option>`'s value is the same as some JSON data, it includes the `selected="selected"` attribute to the option tag as well.  After that, the whole shebang is `.append()`ed to a display.

All of that seems to work fine and dandy, except that the selected option isn't selected. Checking the code in Chrome's Web Dev tools shows that the `selected="selected"` attribute is there. Doing a `console.log()` of the `:selected` options picks them up. However, when I drill down to a specific `<option>` and look at it, is shows the `selected` attribute as set to `false`.

Wha...?

I've tried using the `.select()` and `.attr("selected","selected")` jQuery methods after-the-fact to force the issue, but neither has made any difference.

Can anyone else figure out what's going on here? It might just be my squirrely ignorance, but this seems to me like it should be working.

Code for reference.  `dataArray` is an array of objects.  `$display` is the jQuery wrapped `<table>` the HTML is `.append()`ing to:

```
$orderNumberField = jQuery("#orderNumber");
_orderNumberArray = $.parseJSON( $orderNumberField.val() );

for( n in dataArray ) {
    var _displayString = "";

        // ... other table data cells ...

    _displayString += "<td><select class='orderNumSelect'>";
    _displayString += " <option value=''></option>";
    for( i in _orderNumberArray ){
        _displayString += "<option value='" + _orderNumberArray[i] + "'";
        if( dataArray[n].orderNum == _orderNumberArray[i] ) _displayString += " selected='selected'";
        _displayString += ">" + _orderNumberArray[i] + "</option>";
    }
    _displayString += "</select></td>";

        // ... still other table data cells ...

    $display.append( _displayString );
}
```

Comment: When you say: "However, when I drill down to a specific <option> and look at it, is shows the selected attribute as set to false" do you mean in the html source or in the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's not working on your code,but you can try to generate the elements rather than appending text. I tested out with this code and it works fine

```
<script>
    var dataArray=["test","testm2","Tasat3"];
        function append(){
            var td=document.createElement("td");
            var sel=document.createElement("select");
            var o=document.createElement("option");
            sel.appendChild(o);
            for (n in dataArray){
                o=document.createElement("option");
                o.value=dataArray[n];
                o.text=dataArray[n];
                if (n==1) o.selected=true;
                sel.appendChild(o);
            }
            td.appendChild(sel);

            document.getElementById("display").appendChild(td);
        }
        append();
    </script>
```

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't need to work with these as DOM elements instead of a string, but if such is the case ...  I'll give it a run and reply with the results.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the code outlined above was not at fault for the behavior I described.  There is other code executing after it that resets form inputs. The jQuery selector in the other code was written too generally and was picking up the generated select fields also when it shouldn't have.

Thank you to all the commentors. I did end up rewriting the code to use DOM elements instead of generating a string, which is a little easier to read. Hooray for unintentional side effects.